# UITableView in self.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to customize all my tableViews using this code but Xcode is giving me an error.
I have 2 tableViews and I need to find the tableView != self.tableView.
How can I do that?

```
    for(UITableView *tableView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if (![tableView isEqual:self.tableView]) {
            tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 58, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What sort of error? Paste it here.

Comment: check `if (tableView != self.tableView)`

Comment: and why don't you store table views as ivars?

Comment: -[UIView setSeparatorInset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e734e0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setSeparatorInset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e734e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ea4ae83 0x38da76c7 0x2ea4e7b7 0x2ea4d0af 0x2e99bdc8 0x70883 0x3928c0c3 0x392917d9 0x392919c5 0x393bbdff 0x393bbcc4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like below

```
 for(UIView * view in [self.view subviews])  {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])  {


     UITableView * tblView = (UITableView *) view;
    tblView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 58, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: separatorInset is an object from UITableView so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error you are getting is something to do with the fact you are assuming every View you are getting back from subviews you are passing into a `UITableView` in `UITableView *tableView in [self.view subviews]` but not every view that is returned is going to be a `UITableView` and it is bad practice to assume that they will be. A good idea would be to change the `UITableView` to `UIView` because most if not all `UI` elements are subclassed from `UIView`. Once you have done that you will need to check that it is an instance of `UITableView` and if it is you can start casting `view` to a `UITableView`. See the revised code below for a better understanding.

```
// the issue in your code is that you are getting views back and you are assuming it is 
// a UITableView (So I bet that the error is something do with this) 
for(UIView *view in [[self view] subviews]) {
   // Then we will want to check that it is an instance UITableView 
   // because not everything will be, the initial View will not be 
   // an instance of UITableView
   if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
       UITableView *tb = view
       // Right so we know we have a UITableView
       // Now we want to check that it not equal to self.tableView as your code 
       // indicates you want 
       if(![tb sEqual:[self tableView]]) {
           tb.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 58, 0, 0);
       }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thank you for providing the error

> -[UIView setSeparatorInset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The reason for this is because you will be getting a `UIView` returned in your for loop this is way we have the check to make sure that the view returned is of class `UITableView` and if it is we start casting to it.

Comment: I'm getting this: Property 'separatorInset' not found on object of type 'UIView *'

Comment: If it is from this code try changing `UIView *view` to `id view`

Comment: @user3164474 What exactly happens and where does it get too??? What iOS are you running on??? (**Very Important**)

Comment: Property 'separatorInset' not found on object of type 'const_strong id'

Comment: @user3164474 such as??? and What iOS you running on??? (**Very Important** to know the iOS)

Comment: I've answered: Property 'separatorInset' not found on object of type 'const_strong id'. Thats the when I changed to id warning.

Comment: See my edit I have changed to `UITableView *view in (UITableView *)[[self view] subviews]` and removed the other casts. Leave the checks in still as the object passed to view may still not be a UITableView. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: It Doesn't work and I got this message: Collection expression type 'UITableView *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'

Comment: Property 'separatorInset' not found on object of type 'const_strong id' again.

Comment: Sorry forgot to change one line `tb.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 58, 0, 0);`

Comment: Where does it stop?? Can you do an NSLog within `if(![tb sEqual:[self tableView]]) {` and see if it prints to console.

Comment: It doesn't print in none of these:        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            UITableView *tb = view;
            // Right so we know we have a UITableView
            // Now we want to check that it not equal to self.tableView as your code
            // indicates you want
            NSLog(@"print aa");
            if(![tb isEqual:[self tableView]]) {
                tb.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 58, 0, 0);
                NSLog(@"print");
            }
        }

Comment: `if(![tb isEqual:[self tableView]])` this is failing but just to be sure go and add an nslog just before it.

Comment: I did and it doesn't print;

Comment: Change `[view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]` to `[[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITableView class]];`

Comment: I have tested this code as is and it all works perfect for me. Is it exactly like it is shown in the answer.

Comment: Have you tested with a tableView and a tableView of search display controller?

Comment: Yep, tested by using a SingleViewApplication which moves to (Programmatically) a `UISearchDisplayController` then in `viewDidLoad` I added the above code and it runs successfully.